# Python OpenSSL giving handshake failure

Tags: python, ssl, flask, openssl

I'm trying to update a new valid SSL cert provided by DigiCert on my python flask. The same code with the old expired cert works just fine. However for the renewed cert, it did not recognise my certificate chain and giving error:

```
[root@test~]# openssl s_client -connect somedomain.com:9443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140340901406536:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:744:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 249 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

The weird thing is, when i'm using openssl command to verify my cert chain, everything is working well as follow:

```
[root@test ~]$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile CertChain.crt Server.crt
Server.crt: OK
```

This is my python code

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from flask import Flask, send_file, make_response, request, jsonify, Response
from flask.ext import restful
from flask.ext.restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource

#------------#
context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.use_certificate_file("Server.crt")
context.use_privatekey_file("Server.key")
context.use_certificate_chain_file("CertChain.crt") 
context.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv3)
context.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2)
context.set_cipher_list('ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9443, debug=True, use_reloader=False, ssl_context=context)
```

And for your info key and certificate is matching with no problem

```
[root@test]# openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in Server.crt | openssl md5
(stdin)= adc3de807ec6a02c5ba9da89f3fe5dd5
[root@test]# openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in Server.key | openssl md5
(stdin)= adc3de807ec6a02c5ba9da89f3fe5dd5
```

Is there anything affecting this? Python version? OpenSSL version? My cipher? Any body can help? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution. Previously my certificate chain only contains the Intermediate and Root certificate which is not complete.

The solution is to also include the server certificate into the chain which is weird since `context.use_certificate_file` is already defined.

Anyways, the handshake is now working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 249 bytes

These are not problems of the validation of the certificate.
The clients starts the SSL handshake but the server sends only 7 bytes back, which might be an SSL alert that something is wrong. The server never sends the certificate back so it cannot be a problem of the client side validation.

This means you should better check the server side for problems and not the client side. And since you say that exactly the same code works with the old certificate it can not be a problem of protocol version or ciphers but must relate to the certificate. My guess is thus that the private key you use does not match the certificate you use, which gets not checked when you do the `openssl verify`.

Comment: Hi Steffen, the key is matching with the cert and I have updated my question. Thus, i believe it's not the private key issue.

Comment: @litium: Again, have you looked for error messages on the server side? And how can it be a protocol or cipher thing if you have changed nothing except the certificate?

Comment: Nope there is no error thrown on my server side. Thats what baffles me